# How to enable and disable a button when entering and exiting a geofence

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I want to enable the button when the geofence is entered and disable the button when exiting the geofence. I have tried to get the geofencing exit and entry information using the notification, but it doesn't disable and enable the button.

```java
    private void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
        }
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    } 

    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Anda sudah Mengabsen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void addGeofences() {
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.insufficient_permissions));
            return;
        }
        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this);
    }

    private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        GeofencingRequest geo = getGeofencingRequest();
            if (geo.equals(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)) {
            mAbsen.setEnabled(true);
            mAbsen.setText("Absen");
            frameAbsen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.call_button);
        }else {
            mAbsen.setEnabled(false);
            mAbsen.setText("Tidak");
            //frameAbsen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.disable);
        }
    }
```